# Messages not in use with Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm coding with Scala using Play Framework. As usual, we have all the messages in the messages file. By refactoring and changing the views, there are a bunch of messages that are not being used any more.

As the project is pretty big, I was wondering if there is a way to get a list of all the messages not being used in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not try this module, but it could something that you are looking for

https://github.com/evanbennett/play-messages/blob/master/README.md

> This plugin can:
>
> ... Check for unused message keys ...